# Simple question about the tidal force (Leibniz's notation confuses me)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, tidal-effect

*I started going through Taylor and Wheeler's **Spacetime physics** (standard textbook on special relativity). This is from exercise 2.8.*

Basically we're dropping a bearing ball from a **315 m** height above Earth. Simultaneously, we're dropping another one initially exactly **20 m** above the first one. We neglect air friction.

**g** changes with respect to height, and the lower ball (let's call it **L**) accelerates more than the upper one (**U**). And so it is quite intuitive that the distance between them will slightly increase.

Now the goal is to show that the increase **Δy = 2 mm** when L reaches the ground.

*The point of the exercise is to see how neglectable this tidal force is in the free-float reference frame of the two balls..*

The text explicitly says the fall takes **8 seconds**, which is in line with the fact that **y=gt²/2** (since **y=315 m** and **g≈9.8 m/s²**). But of course, **g** is not constant, so we have to start with:

**g = F/m = (GM/rₒ²)rₒ²/r² = gₒrₒ²/r²**

It is asked to take "the differential **Δg**". Now I am from a pure mathematical background, so I don't really use Leibniz's notation or any of these hand-wavy differential thing. I write **g'(r)**. But here I suppose this is about writing **g'(r) = dg/dr** (and ignore what is a function and what is a number). And then do:

**dg/dr = -2gₒrₒ²/r³** and: **dg = -2gₒrₒ²dr/r³** So I suppose they want: Δg = -2gₒrₒ²Δr/r³

And then get the solution Δy (it should be 2 mm) with **Δy = ½Δgt²**.

I find this confusing. Are they expecting me to plug Δg in there and just substitude with numerical values? What do I do with r and Δr? And what about t? Use the **8 s** given in the text? Isn't all of this an approximation anyway?

**gₒ = 9.8 m/s²**

**rₒ = 6.37 ⋅ 10⁶ m**

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the book, so I can only speculate on what the authors are suggesting. My interpretation is that if you consider a frame accelerating with the lower particle then the acceleration of the upper particle relative to the lower particle throughout the fall is approximately given by:

$$ \Delta a \approx \frac{dg}{dr} \Delta r $$

where the approximation is to assume $dg/dr$ is constant over the small distance moved. $\Delta r$ is the initial separation of $20$ m. Then you simply use the equation for the change in distance between the two particles:

$$ \Delta s = \tfrac{1}{2} \Delta a t^2 $$

If I put in $r = 6.37 \times 10^6 m$ and $g = 9.81 m/sec^2$ I get $\Delta s = 1.97 mm$, which matches the claim in the book.